# How to export a finished BigQuery Job as a CSV

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I know you can run a job and export a csv for an table like under the python example
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery

But Is there a way to export a finished query job as a csv if I have the job ID?  Ultimately I want the query to display in a table on the browser (already have this working) and also have a button where they can download the file as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look up the query job, it will have a destination table specified. If you didn't provide your own table name, this will be a new temporary table created by BigQuery.

You then have two options for getting the results as csv. You can run an export job to export that table as CSV. Or, you can run a tabledata.list() operation on that table and set "alt=csv" which will return the beginning of the table as CSV. Please let me know if you need more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you Jordan!  Have a great day!